# Multiple definition errors when including an audio library

Tags: c++

I'm getting a multiple definition error when I try to compile my program in including the [MiniAudio](https://github.com/mackron/miniaudio) library.
Here's the skeleton of my application:

player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#define MINIAUDIO_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "miniaudio.h"

class Player
{
   ...
}

#endif
```

main.h

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include "player.h"

class Application
{
   ...
}

#endif
```

player.cpp

```
#include "main.h"

void Application::whateverFunc()
{
   ...
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
player.cpp:(.text+0x7d330): multiple definition of `drwav_init_file_w'; obj/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x7d88e): first defined here /usr/bin/ld: obj/player.o: in function `ma_wav_init_memory(void const*, unsigned long, ma_decoding_backend_config const*, ma_allocation_callbacks const*, ma_wav*)': player.cpp:(.text+0x52c24): multiple definition of `ma_wav_init_memory(void const*, unsigned long, ma_decoding_backend_config const*, ma_allocation_callbacks const*, ma_wav*)'; obj/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x530e5): first defined here /usr/bin/ld: obj/player.o: in function `drwav_init_memory':

etc....
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you do a:

```
#define MINIAUDIO_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "miniaudio.h"
```

you get another copy of the definitions.

Quoth the fine manual:

> If you prefer separate .h and .c files, you can find a split version
> of miniaudio in the extras/miniaudio_split folder. From here you can
> use miniaudio as a traditional .c and .h library - just add
> miniaudio.c to your source tree like any other source file and include
> miniaudio.h like a normal header.

Source https://github.com/mackron/miniaudio

Comment: So either using this split version – or if applicable, moving the `#define #include` into `player.cpp` to get that implemented only once...

Answer (score 2):

If multiple files will include the **miniaudio.h** then you will have that many definitions/implementations. In your case, you have the impl of miniaudio in **obj/main.o** and also in **obj/player.o**, as stated in :

```
obj/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x530e5): first defined here /usr/bin/ld: obj/player.o: in function `drwav_init_memory'
```

To avoid this, you must include this once (as their definition says "Do the following in **one** source file).
[image: MiniAudioDocumentation]

The solution to this is to create a Context.h file, Then the player and main can, both, include Context.h .

ex:

Context.h

```
#ifndef CONTEXT_H
#define CONTEXT_H

#define MINIAUDIO_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "miniaudio.h"

#endif
```

Player.h

```
#include "Context.h"
```

main.h

```
#include "Context.h"
```